# Как парсить динамический контент через JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

У меня стоит задача пропарсить сайт ria.ru.
Я выбрал для этого JSoup.

Так как часть контента сайта генерируется скриптами, я не могу, например загрузить ссылку на картинку в свой объект класса EntryNews:

```
public EntryNews(String imgRef, String newsRef, String title, String announce, String date) {
        this.imgRef = imgRef;
        this.newsRef = newsRef;
        this.title = title;
        this.announce = announce;
        this.date = date;
    }
```

Ведь тот html который видит парсер

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ria.ru/").get();
```

не содержит многих css-классов, которые можно увидеть если например просмотреть код страницы в хроме.

Уже третий день не могу разобраться - как мне узнать откуда подгружается этот динамический контент?
В моем предыдущем вопросе мне посоветовали выгрузить сайт через wget и глянуть откуда скрипты берут новое содержимое. Однако там я нашел только вот это (в принципе мало похожее на нечто полезное):

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { checkBannerHeight(17); });</script></div></div><div xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" class="day_news"><div class="day_news_wrapper">
```

Ткните пожалуйста, куда мне посмотреть и/или скажите что почитать на эту тему.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился через Jsoup добавлением строки `userAgent("Mozilla")`. Дело оказалось в том что сервер не хотел предоставлять контент пользователю без `userAgent`

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понял, что именно вызывает у вас затруднение.

Если речь идет о том, чтобы получить CSS какой-то страницы, то JSOUP не для этого создан, он преимущественно для разбора DOM. И есть, к примеру, вот [такой](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) парсер для CSS.

Если речь идет о динамически подгружаемом контенте, то советую посмотреть в [эту](http://phantomjs.org/) и [эту](http://casperjs.org/) сторону.

Возможно,  [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Answer (score 1):

jsoup не работает с js, смотрите в сторону htmlunit или Selenium. Вот хороший [мануал](https://kreisfahrer.gitbooks.io/selenium-webdriver/content/index.html)

Comment: у меня java. я в тегах указал :)

Вопрос решился через Jsoup добавлением строки userAgent("Mozilla"). Дело оказалось в том что сервер не хотел предоставлять контент пользователю без userAgent